# How can I use a for-loop to double the previous element each time?

Tags: java, for-loop

In Java...

To print the following numbers: (1, 2, 4, 8, 16...etc).

I have this so far:

```
int[] b = new int[16];
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
```

Comment: What's the array for? And why are you incrementing instead of doubling? And why are you stopping at 16?

Comment: @shmosel you mean what is the purpose of the array? Its just an exercise from a book. I'm able to get (2,4, 6, 8...) but not the actual double each time.

Comment: @shmosel  OK, I get the incrementing part now, as you suggested I will use i*=2. Stopping at 16 because thats the size of the array, however I will now use 'i < b.length'.

Comment: I still don't understand how the array is relevant to this exercise.

Comment: @shmosel The question is..... Create another array, b, of size 16 in which the elements are initialised to the values 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, … , 32768 respectively.  Then print the array elements on the screen.

Comment: if you want to fill the array, you should write that and not 'print the following values'...and to get 16 values you should loop until the VALUE is 32768

Comment: Then `i < b.length` won't work. You need a separate index variable. Or just increment `i++` and set `b[i] = 1 << i`.

Comment: that is, Korashen's answer below is probably the best way to go

Comment: Or how about `int[] b = IntStream.iterate(1, i -> i * 2).limit(16).toArray();`

Comment: well, that's the one I would like the most (but probably not for someone learning for-loops = do we still need them?!)

Comment: @shmosel  trying to do it the non-stream way, sorry

Comment: I got it this way... I did for(i=1; i < 65536; i*=2) {System.out.printLn(i)}

Comment: So I was under the impression that if I did i<16 then it would loop 16 times, not that it would see it as the actual value, thats why I then tried (based on @CarlosHeuberger answer) and did i<65536).

Comment: well, i still would do `for (int i... i < b.length; i++)` together with a second variable `value` (answer from @Korashen) - it uses an additional variable, but is more likely to reflect what is being intended: fill the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void process()
{
    int value = 1;
    int maxItterations = 8;
    int[] targetArray = new int[maxItterations];

    for(int index = 0; index < maxItterations; index++)
    {
        // Store current value
        targetArray[index] = value;

        // Duplicate the value for the next itteration
        value = value * 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: add the array to this and it is the best solution to what is being requested IMO

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Done!. Thanks for the idea. Cudos to you.

Answer (score 2):

Another simple way (and IMHO better representation of what is wanted):

```
int limit = 100; // or whatever is requested

for (int i = 1; i <= limit; i *= 2) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: but after the request changed to 'fill the array', I would tend to use `i` as an index and having a second variable with the value to be doubles... mostly Korashen's answer, so I won't change mine

Answer (score 0):

You could just keep multiple a variable in loop's body:

```
long number = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
    System.out.println(number);
    number *= 2L;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use bitwise shift and start with `int i = 1`:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 16; i <<=1){
    /*...*/
}
```